hwo to update point field in directus in a flow with update data block
im trying to update a "point" field in directus flow.
but it always writes "stringify requires a valid GeoJSON Feature or geometry object as input"
tried:
    "address_map": [
      -123.72778058052172,
      65.4859933375385
    ]
}

and
"address_map": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -123.72778058052172,
      65.4859933375385
    ]
  }

but it didnt work .
any ideas how to do it ?
